# Close due to ensuing discussion and not original question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question here was directly prompted by this QA:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85921/how-do-i-explain-to-hr-that-my-work-experience-is-relevant-even-if-it-doesnt-mat

I'm not sure if I think this should be closed. On the one hand, I'm fine with the original question. I don't *like* it but I'm fine with it.

On the other hand, the ensuing discussion in the comments is shaping up to be a flamewar because of the argumentativeness of the person who asked the original question.

Is it appropriate to close (or in my case flag, since I can't close) a question because of it's ensuing discussion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely appropriate to flag it. Since the question is on-topic and generally salvageable, we can step in to either simply ask the warring parties to knock it off, edit the question, or lock it to prevent further derailing.

Generally we wouldn't close a question in that situation unless it was off-topic or otherwise unsuitable in the first place, since doing so wouldn't stop the flame war anyway.

For this particular question, I've reworded the title, cleaned up the comments that are no longer relevant and am keeping an eye on it to see if it continues going south.